# Changing JSON file loaded into table by clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I've been able to get a JSON file to load into a table fine, but I want to have multiple JSON files and change which one is loaded into the table based on which button has been pressed. I thought I could just make it change the variable `data`, but then the table still stays the same (I'm assuming you have to make it refresh some how?).

Also, on a side note, is it possible to have the prices have a space between them?

`test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Hello World">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="data1.json"></script>
  <script src="data2.json"></script>

  <script>
  $(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
      data: data_one
    });

    $('#data1').on('click', function(event) {
      $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data_one
      });
    });

    $('#data2').on('click', function(event) {
      $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data_two
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Test</h3>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="data1">Data 1</a>
      <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="data2">Data 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <table id="table" class="table table-bordered" data-search="true" data-show-toggle="true">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-field="prices" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <hr>
      <p><small><a href="www.google.com">Google</a> didn't help me</small></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body> 
</html>
```

`data1.json`:

```
var data_one = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "test0",
    "prices": [
      "$0",
      "$5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test1",
    "prices": [
      "$4",
      "$1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test2",
    "prices": [
      "$2",
      "$3"
    ]
  },
];
```

`data2.json`:

```
var data_two = [
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "test4",
    "prices": [
      "$1",
      "$2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "test5",
    "prices": [
      "$6",
      "$5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "test6",
    "prices": [
      "$9",
      "$7"
    ]
  },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the 'load' method when updating the data in the table:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({ data: data_one });

    $('#data1').on('click', function(event) {
      $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', { data: data_one });
    });

    $('#data2').on('click', function(event) {
      $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', { data: data_two });
    });
  });
</script>
```

For some reason you cannot initially load the data with load method, only update. You can also append data with "append" method and do lot of cool stuff. Check out the documentation here: [Bootstrap Table Documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Now to figure out how to make it noticable which button has been clicked last... :-)

Comment: Nice one @JetpackPony.

Comment: @user5368737 use JQuery's addClass and removeClass like this https://jsfiddle.net/h4dLjnt6/
This is obviously not a strong design though and should not be used as it is :-)

Comment: @JetpackPony seems that it goes back to the same colour after clicking it, so both buttons stay the same colour. I will try some stuff and figure it out though.

Comment: @user5368737 wierd. I just tried the same code I sent you and it works fine. Make sure that on click you are removing the class from all other buttons. Maybe use something like `$('.btn').removeClass("clicked");` before adding class to current button

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't need all the `ready` functions, just one (the functions that look like `$(function () {..}`).

2) Also, you're not calling the plugin on that element again when you click a button - you have to explicitly do that.

3) Finally, you've not added an event listener to your second button - you added a duplicate listener to your first button.

4) You should remove the inline `onclick="data1()"` and `onclick="data2()"` from your HTML buttons.

```
$(function () {

  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data_one
  });

  $('#data1').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
      data: data_one
    });
  });

  $('#data2').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
      data: data_two
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: I understand 1) and 2) (assuming you are talking about the .bootstrapTable), but not 3). I thought that if I pasted what you wrote above into my code it should work, right?

Comment: Also take a look at 4) which I added. If you're adding listeners to elements with jQuery you don't then need to add inline click handlers.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I copy and pasted what you wrote above and removed the inline click handler, but pressing the button doesn't actually change the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are not integrating data2() function. You can write your code as below.

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
      data: data_one
    });
  });

function data1(){
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
      data: data_one
    });
}
function data2(){
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
      data: data_two
    });
}
```

Comment: You're suggesting the OP use inline click handlers when the OP is clearly using jQuery. You shouldn't mix and match like that.